# What is the difference between 'associations hidden between objects' and 'hidden associations between objects'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between 'associations hidden between objects' and 'hidden associations between objects'?
Aren't both referring to the associations that are hidden and not the objects themselves?

Comment: In both expressions, "hidden" refers to the associations. But in first sentence, we literrally understand that an association can hide inside an  an objects list. In the second one, it is clear that "associations between objects are hidden".

Comment: But are the ideas for both expressions the same essentially?

Comment: In the first expression, associations are not necessarily associations between objects: they just hide somewhere in objects definition.

Comment: The ideas are **not** the same for both expressions. _Associations_ and _associations between objects_ aren't the same idea; _associations hidden between objects_ isn't the same idea as _hidden associations between objects_. You can't just put words anywhere in sentence, like Russian.

Answer (score 3):

**Associations hidden between objects**:

- There are some associations
- They are hidden
- Their hiding place is between objects

**Hidden associations between objects**:

- There are some objects
- These objects have associations with each other
- These associations are hidden

**Conclusion**:

- In the first phrase the associations could be any associations; in the second phrase they are "associations between objects".
- In the first phrase the associations hiding place is "between objects"; in the second phrase they could be hiding anywhere

***No, they are not the same.***